# drag and drop in datagridview winform

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I am trying to create a datagridview and want drag and drop feature in that datagridview. The user can select datagridview header and drop in another place that will rearrange. And when user select header and drop in text box the datagridview data group according that data. I try to use this example [drag and drop in datagridview](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12539/How-to-drag-information-from-a-DataGridView-contro)

Comment: And what is the problem? Where did you fail?

Comment: @etaiso  basically i try with that example but this not help me and the real is that i never create such this type of datagridview i see same feature in dev express datagridview . Is this possible or any example that can help me